# lock screen behaviour for my app in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to simulate the lock screen behaviour inside my application. Is there any way I can create the same behaviour for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change or override the system lock screen, however there is nothing stopping you from creating something that kicks-in before the system lock screen and looks similar.

Just use a timer (`DispatcherTimer`) which is started after each user interaction with the screen (i.e. each interaction will cancel the previous timer). When the timer ticks, slide an element (an `Image` perhaps) over the screen. Handle manipulation events in order to allow the user to slide it upwards.